# Re-Focus Browser in Javascript when Dragging File from Desktop

Tags: javascript, browser, focus, drag-and-drop

When I drag a file from the desktop to the browser, and I keep the browser in focus (Safari or FireFox for now), I know everything works right (dragging, having the app respond, etc.).  I am also able to un-focus the browser, by clicking on my desktop for example (keeping the browser in view), and when I drag the file to the browser, I am still able to process the drag events, which is cool.

I'm just wondering how I can refocus the browser when:

1) It's not in focus, and
2) when it's not in focus, I drag something over it.

I can do something like `window.focus()`, but that doesn't bring the whole browser back into focus out of the things on my desktop.  What line of js code do I need to make the browser refocus, like how when you drag a folder to an unfocused/blurred Finder window on the Mac and it pops into focus after a second or two?

Then it's onto processing the dragged info...

Comment: not possible for security reason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript cannot access the browser like that and cannot control the operating system's focus which is what you are really asking for.

Comment: makes sense.  just wondering if it was possible.  I'm still able to drag and drop without getting the browser into focus which is interesting...